# Dumping an array to a sheet changes the datatype

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very simple question.
It seems that some automatic Type Conversion is going on when I dump an Array to a sheet.
Easy example:

```
Dim bla as variant
redim bla(0 to 1, 0 to 1)
bla(0,0) = "123"
Activesheet.Range("A1").Resize(2,2).Value = bla
```

Result:
The cell "A1" contains a NUMERIC VALUE with the value 123 instead of a string.
Is this the expected behaviour?
Are there workarounds that make excel discover that i actually passed a string?
The system (i.e., vba) knows that it is a string. EG:

```
TypeName(bla(0,0))
```

returns "String"

Thanks!

Comment: You need to format as text, so if typename(bla(0,0))="String" then activesheet.range("a1").numberformat="@"

Comment: Thanks. I know that is possible, but I consider it is a workaround. Just imagine an array of 1000x1000 with different datatypes. You would need to loop over all of the entries in the sheet and individually use an excel function to set the correct Datatype. That completely eliminates the speed advantage of the dump method. Is this the only way to solve the problem without looping over each and every entry of the array?

Comment: Why do you want to pass it as a string?

Comment: Where is the array populated, can you prefix numeric entries with ' on population to make them text?

Comment: why not just format the entire range after the dump: `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(2,2).NumberFormat = "@"`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The array is used in a lot of internal operations. Prepending a ' to every string is not an option.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman: I used that approach. The values do display ok in Excel after that operation. But excel still considers them as numbers. That means, a comparison operation in excel between a number formatted as string and the string containing the same content will result into "FALSE". My aim is exactly that excel does that kind of comparison (i.e., the string "123" that is found elsewhere on an excel sheet should be equal to the "123" entry in the array that is copied to the sheet) .

Comment: I don't know what your comparison operation is exactly, but what about forcing the string in the operation ... for example `=vlookup(text(A1,"@"),Sheet2!A1:B1000,2,0)`

Comment: I think you actually need to apply your formatting prior to dumping in your arrays data ie. `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(2,2).NumberFormat = "@"` followed by `Activesheet.Range("A1").Resize(2,2).Value = bla`. If you set the `NumberFormat` afterwards Excel does appear to continue to register the existing values as a numeric (with no green triangle in the top left hand corner of the cell to indicate a numeric held as text).

Comment: @andshrew: Your solution was the one that I finally used. If you do not do the Numberformat BEFORE the dumping, you end up with nicely formatted numbers that are not considered strings by excel. Then, the only workaround would be what Scott recommends. But I did not want to do this workaround in all the other parts of my excel sheets, I wanted to have the same datatype (string) in excel as in my variant. All other things would have complicated everything. So I ended up using andshrew's approach. I actually found out about that before andshrew's  comment, so this is just for completeleness.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!